# Should objects be created chronologically as class defined?

Tags: php, mysql, class, object

I am having a strange error while creating objects. While I create an objects in chronological orders as classed defined, it is going on good. But when I change the order or object creation, it gives error.

The classes I am using are as follows:

```
<?php
class dbClass{
private $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, $connection;
function __construct(){
    require_once("system/configuration.php");
    $this->dbHost = $database_host;
    $this->dbUser = $database_username;
    $this->dbPass = $database_password;
    $this->dbName = $database_name;
}
function __destruct(){
    if(!$this->connection){

    } else{
        mysql_close($this->connection);
    }
}
function mysqlConnect(){
    $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass) or die("MySQL connection failed!");
    mysql_select_db($this->dbName,$this->connection);
}
function mysqlClose(){
    if(!$this->connection){

    } else{
        mysql_close($this->connection);
    }
}
}
class siteInfo{
private $wTitle, $wName, $wUrl;
function __construct(){
    require_once("system/configuration.php");
    $this->wTitle = $website_title;
    $this->wName = $website_name;
    $this->wUrl = $website_url;
}
function __destruct(){

}
function showInfo($keyword){
    if($keyword=="wTitle"){
        return $this->wTitle;
    }
    if($keyword=="wName"){
        return $this->wName;
    }
    if($keyword=="wUrl"){
        return $this->wUrl;
    }
    }
    }
?>
```

The problem is when I create objects in the following order, it is working perfectly:

```
include("system/systemClass.php");
$dbConnection = new dbClass();
$dbConnection -> mysqlConnect();
$siteInfo = new siteInfo();
```

But if I change the order to following

```
include("system/systemClass.php");
$siteInfo = new siteInfo();
$dbConnection = new dbClass();
$dbConnection -> mysqlConnect();
```

It gives error!
`Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user '#####'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/#####/public_html/#####/system/systemClass.php on line 19
MySQL connection failed!`

Comment: I think sitInfo contains information from the database, which connection hasn't been made yet is the mysqlConnect is called afterwards.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Yep. Hidden assignment of variables. This is one cause why **bad** PHP code can make one want to die...

Comment: I'd say at least one of your problems is that you are defining all your classes in a single file - which is typically poor practice.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting No, the site info variables comes from the configuration.php file. There the variables are simply listed like $website_title = "My website"; etc. It's information does not come from mysql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the unconventional use of a configuration file that is read ONCE, but should be used in all classes.

When you instantiate the `dbclass` first, the configuration is read, probably variables get assigned, and you use these in the constructor.

After that, instantiating `siteinfo` will not read that file again, which is less harmful, because you only end up with an empty object that does return a lot of null, but does work.

The other way round, you get a `siteinfo` object with all the info, but a nonworking `dbclass`.

My advice: Don't use a configuration file that way.

First step: Remove the `require_once` - you need that file to be read multiple times.

Second step: Don't read the file in the constructor. Add one or more parameters to the constructor function and pass the values you want to be used from the outside.

Info: You can use PHP code files that configure stuff, but you shouldn't define variables in them that get used outside. This will work equally well:

```
// configuration.php
return array(
    'database_host' => "127.0.0.1",
    'database_user' => "root",
    // ...
);


// using it:
$config = require('configuration.php'); // the variable now has the returned array
```